# Database is not working

Tags: android, sqlite

kindly help me here is my code . Before Launching it doesnot Show any error . But 
When i Run the app 
it Does not show any data .
When i check database file there was no table Created 
Kidly Help me

Thanks & Regards
 Gurmeet Singh

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;
    String TableName = "Dictionary";
    String Data="";
    try {
           myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Punjabishabdkosh", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

           myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                     + TableName
                     + " (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR);");

           myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
                     + TableName
                     + " (Field1, Field2)"
                     + " VALUES ('Gurmeet', Tiwana);");


           Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);

           int Column1 = c.getColumnIndex("Field1");
           int Column2 = c.getColumnIndex("Field2");

           c.moveToFirst();
           if (c != null) {

              do {
                String Name = c.getString(Column1);
                int Age = c.getInt(Column2);
                Data =Data +Name+"/"+Age+"\n";
              }while(c.moveToNext());
           }
           TextView tv = new TextView(this);
           tv.setText(Data);
           setContentView(tv);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Error", e);
    } finally {
        if (myDB != null)
           myDB.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the locgcat se if there is any Error printed..

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve an integer from Field2? You insert Tiwana into Field2 and then later on you try c.getInt(column2) which is not an integer.

Comment: Please format your code properly.  It's very difficult to read with the indentation incorrect.

Comment: @bakriOnFire is probably right.  You should not ignore exceptions like this, `Log.e("Error", "Error", e);`.  What is in logcat?

Answer (score 1):

The following statement contains an error:

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
                 + TableName
                 + " (Field1, Field2)"
                 + " VALUES ('Gurmeet', Tiwana);");
```

As both `Field1` and `Field2` are `VARCHAR` fields, the word "Tiwana" needs to be wrapped in single quotes, so I assume the insert is failing, that's why you don't see any data. Change the statement to:

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
                 + TableName
                 + " (Field1, Field2)"
                 + " VALUES ('Gurmeet', 'Tiwana');");
```